# What is the song playing during battle scenes when Ushio calls the Beast Spear?

Tags: music, ushio-to-tora

Is there any official OST of *Ushio to Tora (2015)*?
I am pretty much interested in the soundtrack during battle scenes when Ushio calls the Beast Spear.

Comment: I removed the last question about the genre of the music, since it is off-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there definitely is an official soundtrack for Ushio to Tora. You can purchase one from [here](http://www.cdjapan.co.jp/product/TKCA-74278)

As for your battle scene music, someone [recreated the music](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kTD4VKI5HCQ) on YouTube that you might find interesting.

Comment: Yes, it's nice, but I prefer the original one, so much more aggressive. Also the track list is pretty small, not sure if the one I need is really there:1  
混ぜるな危険 (TVサイズ)
2  
HERO
3  
うしおのテーマ
4  
とらのテーマ
5  
槍の男 (ほか30曲予定)

Comment: @Ascorpio The track listing on cdjapan is just the first 5 out of ~35 total. The album doesn't actually come out for another two weeks, so you're going to have to wait until then.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the piece you're looking for is the one that is recreated in [the Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kTD4VKI5HCQ) that [Tyhja's answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/26378/) links to, that's track #35 on [the first volume of the soundtrack](http://vgmdb.net/album/54056), titled "Yari no Otoko 2" ("Man with the Spear 2").

Note that the start of the recreated version of the piece corresponds to about 25 seconds into the actual track. Here is a 15-second extract: https://clyp.it/bdj1z10k.